# C# discount on radio buttons

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I need to create a membership that gives the user a series of options to choose from. One of the options gives them either a discount of their overall payment cost of either 0%, 2%, or 5%. For some reason my C# code is putting 0% into the overall discount textbox.

C#:

```cs
Int discount = 0;
If(basicradiobt.checked)
 Discount *= 0;
If (regularradiobt.checked)
Discount *=2;
If (premiumradiobt.checked) 
Discount *=5;
Totaldiscounttxtbx.text = discount.tosting();
```

Comment: Can you provide some additional details? Also, can you copy and paste the code you have so far, there are several typos' apparent in your post.

Comment: Int Basicdiscount = 0;
Int Regulardiscount = 2;
Int Premiumdiscount = 5;

If (Basicradiobt.checked)
{
Basicdiscount %=0;
Totaldiscounttxtbx.text = Basicdiscount.tostring();
} 
If (Regularradiobt.checked)
{
Regularradiobt %=2;
Regulardiscount.tostring();
} 
If (Premiumradiobt.checked)
{
Premiumradiobt %=5;
Premiumdiscount.tostring();
}

Comment: Sorry I’ve changed it a wee bit but still isn’t working I can’t fully copy it cause I’m using my phone cause my laptop dose not have any wifi or data.

Comment: Hmmm, if you are asking for people to help you, you should make it easy for them to do so by posting the actual problem that you have in the original question. You can't expect people to do extra work to help you because your laptop doesn't have wifi or data (did you consider creating a hotspot on your phone)? I tried to add the pasted code from your comment to the question for you (this one time) but someone else seems to have already edited the question.

Comment: FWIW, the answer from @Bogdan_Doicin answers your original question. Changing the multiplication (i.e. the "*=") of 0 to a modulo operation (i.e. the %=) will result in the same problem. Also, your first version (with Bogdan's answer) is probably closer to producing the correct result when compared to the later version.

Comment: Ok thank you sorry I’m on a stupid plan where I can’t hotspot and the hospitals wifi isn’t working. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @GMc I sent an edit for review. This is what it might block yours.

Comment: @TaylaBrown I didn't know you needed a data plan to be able to hotspot.

Comment: You're welcome. If you think my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted so as other users will be faster helped in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You have two mistakes:

1. You declare the variable `discount`, then you use it as `Discount`. Because C# is case-sensitive, they are treated as two separate variables;
2. You declare the variable `discount`, initializing it with 0. Suppose you fixed the mistake above, you multiply its value (0) with 0, 2 or 5, respectively. Any number times 0 equals 0.

And I guess that in the line

`Totaldiscounttxtbx.text = discount.tosting();`

you actually meant

`Totaldiscounttxtbx.text = discount.tostring();`

**Later edit, taking into consideration your comments**: if you just want to display the discount value, you could do something like this:

```
int discount;
if (basicradiobt.Checked) discount=0;
if (regularradiobt.Checked) discount=2;
if (premiumradiobt.Checked) discount=5;
totaldiscounttxtbx.text=discount.tostring();
```

If you're interested in the final price, **after the discount was applied**, try this:

```
float startingprice;
if (basicradiobt.Checked) startingprice*=1;;
if (regularradiobt.Checked) startingprice*=0.98;
if (premiumradiobt.Checked) startingprice*=0.95;
totaldiscounttxtbx.text=startingprice.tostring();
```

(Because I typed fast, I didn't bother with case-sensitivity. But I don't have a compiler on my back either.)